# How to combine pandas index columns in a method chain?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm working with a multi-index pandas dataframe. My goal is to combine two index columns into one, without breaking out from a chain of methods.

Example:

A have the following pandas dataframe:

```
In[1]: df
Out[1]: 
                    value
year type color          
2018 A    red   -0.236022
          blue  -1.030577
     B    red    1.197374
          blue  -0.496247
2019 A    red   -0.066938
          blue   0.087585
     B    red   -1.702598
          blue   0.085282
```

Now, I want to perform a chain of methods on this dataframe. Somewhere in the middle of these methods, I want to combine two index columns into one. For instance, I perform a query (type==A), and then combine two index columns (year and color) and then multiply (by 4). All this without breaking out from the chain:

```
df2 = df \
  .query('type=="A"') \
  .reset_index('type', drop=True) \
  .combine_indexes(["year", "type"]) \ # <- this is what I'm missing
  .multiply(4)
```

The desired output is:

```
In[3]: df2
Out[3]: 

               value
year-color          
2018-red   -0.944089
2018-blue  -4.122310
2019-red   -0.267752
2019-blue   0.350339
```

I made up 'combine_indexes' method in this example. Does anyone know if there's something equivalent to this? I know how to combine two index columns but only if I break out from the chain. I need something that is compatible with chaining.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without breaking chain, I would move `set_index` last:

```
(df.query('type=="A"')
   .reset_index('type',drop=True)
   .mul(4)
   .assign(year_color=lambda x: [f'{a}-{b}' for a,b in x.index])
   .set_index('year_color')
)
```

Output (original values are `np.arange(8)`)

```
            value
year_color       
2018-red        0
2018-blue       4
2019-red       16
2019-blue      20
```

Answer (score 1):

On the question of how to join the index levels, let's try `Index.map`:

```
tmp = df.query('type == "A"').droplevel('type')
# The money line:
tmp.index = tmp.index.map('{0[0]}-{0[1]}'.format)                                                                                              
tmp.index.name = 'year-color'                                                                                                                  

tmp                                                                                                                                            

               value
year-color          
2018-red   -0.236022
2018-blue  -1.030577
2019-red   -0.066938
2019-blue   0.087585
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But as I indicated in my question, I'm looking for a method on dataframes, so that it can be part of a method chain.